# kubernetes pod running on google compute engine not able to access metadata service

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I am trying to run google cloud python sdk from inside a k8 pod, running on google compute engine. There is a service account attached to the VM, which is giving it access to the secrets manager. I am able to access secrets manager from the host, however running the python sdk from k8 pod complains of not able to access the metadata service

```
>>> secret_id = 'unskript_test'
>>> name = client.secret_path(project_id, secret_id)
>>> response = client.get_secret(request={"name": name})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 67, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1630634901.103779641","description":"Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Enginemetadata service. Compute Engine Metadata server unavailable","file":"src/core/lib/security/credentials/plugin/plugin_credentials.cc","file_line":90,"grpc_status":14}"
>
```

metadata.google.internal doesnt get resolved from the k8 pod

```
jovyan@jovyan-25ca6c8c-157d-49e5-9366-f9d57fcb7a9f:~$ wget http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true
--2021-09-03 02:11:19--  http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true
Resolving metadata.google.internal (metadata.google.internal)... failed: Name or service not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘metadata.google.internal’
```

However, host is able to resolve it

```
ubuntu@gcp-test-proxy:~$ wget http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true
--2021-09-03 02:11:27--  http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true
Resolving metadata.google.internal (metadata.google.internal)... 169.254.169.254
Connecting to metadata.google.internal (metadata.google.internal)|169.254.169.254|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden
2021-09-03 02:11:27 ERROR 403: Forbidden.
```

How can i make the pod resolve metadata.google.internal?

Comment: Hello @Amit. Was your problem resolved? If yes, can you mention the steps you have taken to solve the problem. Or if the given answer helped can you accept or upvote it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with microk8s not copying host etc hosts entry to the pods. Once we moved to k3, it got resolved

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by Kubernetes pod not being able to resolve the `metadata.google.internal` DNS name to proper IP. You host machine probably has an entry in `/etc/hosts` that hardcodes that domain to the IP: 169.254.169.254.

You should be able to replicate that in your Pod by modifying its `/etc/hosts` file.

Just remember that this will only work on VMs running on GCP. Outside, the IP address 169.254.169.254 is just another IP address that has not special meaning.

EDIT: Just checked /etc/hosts on one of my GCP VMs, and here's what I found:

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
169.254.169.254 metadata.google.internal metadata
```

So just try copying that last line to your pods `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Thanks @maciek. The issue was with microk8s not copying host etc hosts entry to the pods. Once we moved to k3, it got resolved